# Traefik and URL redirects, how it can be done (K3S environment)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have quite simple scenario:
Ingress --> Service --> Pod with some Web service

What is needed:
somedomain.com/prefix1 --> Service1
somedomain.com/prefix2 --> Service2
somedomain.com/prefix3 --> Service3

It works for static pages only
If Web service redirects to any other path, it does know about this `/prefixN`, I can see that browser is trying to reach `/news`, but Traefik does not know anything about this path and it fails.

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: stripprefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /speed
      - /nginx
      - /jenkins
...

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: services-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-stripprefix@kubernetescrd
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /speed
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: openspeedtest-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /nginx
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /jenkins
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: jenkins-service
```

Workaround for Jenkins: I can use option for Jenkins `--prefix=/jenkins`, but is is not the common solution for all Web resouces.
For example, lets take openspeedtest Pod/container. I can see openspeedtest page by /speed path, but once the Start button is pushed, Openspeedtest makes user go to `/`, but Ingress does now know anything about it and can't route traffic properly.
I belive this task should have a simple and robust solution, please advice.

Comment: There is no robust solution when it comes to redirects. It requires the service you are redicting to, to be configured properly in order to handle redicts or, If you are lucky, to let you set a context path.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the question is to use host separation, not path seperation:
[How to display speedtester in kubernetes using ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983500/how-to-display-speedtester-in-kubernetes-using-ingress)